# Product Attribute Reindexing Error: Zend Problem

Tags: error, sql, reindex, zend-framework

When attempting to run a reindex on the Product Attributes section of Magento, I get the message "There was a problem with the reindexing process."

I've managed to get an error log out of the particular problem, and it is as follows:

---

```
Product Attributes index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row' in /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(48): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'cataloginventor...', Array, false)
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Indexer_Stock), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'cataloginventor...', Array, false)
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('cataloginventor...', 'cataloginventor...', false)
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Indexer/Stock.php(251): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Indexer_Stock->reindexAll()
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(252): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /home/mysite/public_html/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /home/mysite/public_html/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row' in /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(48): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'cataloginventor...', Array, false)
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Indexer_Stock), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'cataloginventor...', Array, false)
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('cataloginventor...', 'cataloginventor...', false)
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Indexer/Stock.php(251): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Indexer_Stock->reindexAll()
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(252): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /home/mysite/public_html/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /home/mysite/public_html/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

---

I understand that there's clearly an issue going on here with a SQL query launched by the Zend file returning more than one result when it can only handle a singular result, but what isn't clear to me is how the reindexing was working just fine, then, after adjusting a few products through the Magento interface, it suddenly ceases function.

I would think that the Magento interface would have operations in place to prevent any cardinality violations from occurring.

What I'm wondering is, of course how to resolve the issue, but also to go about preventing the cardinality issues from cropping up again, especially given that there's apparently an issue with Magento preventing said issues.

Additional information:
I'm using the Multi-Warehouse extension and the M2E extension.
The other reindexes appear to be working fine.

Comment: UPDATE: I've gone and combed the database for any data that would cause a cardinality issue; by the looks of it the problem lies with any of the "cataloginventory" tables. Yet when I looked through those tables and ran queries to highlight duplicate entries, I found nothing amiss. I also checked the catalog_product_entity table for duplicate skus, per the recommendation of another individual with the same issue. Further research indicated that mySQL has issues where it will randomly report the cardinality incorrectly. How do I tell if this is one of those times?